# Cannot edit xorg.conf file

Tags: graphics, ubuntu-drivers, xorg.conf

First off just want to thank you all in advance because I am a total noob!

- I'm trying to improve video quality as it is very choppy.
- Running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- On a Gateway Notebook AMD E-300 APU with Radeon HD6310 graphics card
- Motherboard V2,05/NE51B
- 4GB ram, 320gb HD
- I do not know if the correct video driver is installed.
- I was led to this site on installing the video card driver and improving video quality
  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
- So I am trying to edit the xorg.conf file in order to enable DRI3 as suggested in the link above. Not even sure if this will resolve to video quality issues though...
- So I can't edit the xorg.conf file.
- Can't open through Ubuntu regular text editor as it says I do not have permission even though I am logged in and am the only Admin user.
- And when searching for the files through the editor I cannot find the actual xorg.conf file. But I found 3 files named xorg.conf.save, xorg.conf.save1 and xorg.conf.save2 which I cannot view due to permissions...
- Using sudo commands in the terminal It appears that I was able to open the xorg.conf file with nano but it is blank. All 3 files listed above show up as blank...

I really have no idea what to do now...

Please help!

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Well since nobody was willing to help me here, I figured I'll post what I did in case anyone cares...

Upgraded my RAM 8GB and installed a solid state hard drive.

Video is no longer choppy.

Thanks...

Comment: Oh forgot to add that I installed the latest Ubuntu 20 on the laptop. So no longer running Ubuntu 18.